# Symfony 5 / EasyAdmin 3 / exception when trying to turn filters on

Tags: filter, symfony5, easyadmin3

Symfony 5.2.6 (env: dev, debug: true)
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 11:52:41) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
EasyAdmin 3.2.7

Simple user entity (using uuids) with manytomany relation to userRoles.
Adding filters in adminUserCrudController

```
public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
{
    return $filters
        ->add('name')
    ;
}
```

[btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mPCI.png)
trying to display them (index view - click on button) throws an exception in network panel.

Warning: parse_str() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

http://app.lan/admin?crudAction=renderFilters&crudControllerFqcn=App%5CController%5CAdmin%5CUserCrudController&menuIndex=1&signature=WhqkGhBhzEHyJQmfp9VqlfXE2R901PkU0s15NuC2mEQ&submenuIndex=-1

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Va3i.png)

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

firefox ClearURLs Add-on was the problem.
Sorry for disturbing, hope this helps someday someone :}